# Interrupted Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade, Dual Boot

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, dual-boot, upgrade

Whilst upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 via the update manager, a power shortage in the building caused my desktop to fail. This was in the installation phase. I am now able to boot the PC in Windows 7, but not in Ubuntu. Booting in Ubuntu gives me the log-in screen, which is still marked with 12.04 LTS. After selecting my user account, the PC briefly shows a black screen before returning to the log-in screen.

How can I finish the installation? Since there is no valuable data on the Ubuntu partition, a clean re-install is an option. Is this possible (via USB for example), without touching the Windows partition? I heard re-installing Ubuntu can erase the whole hard-drive, and re-installing Windows would be a hassle I can do without.

Many thanks
Egon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Put the live iso on your Usb-stick.
Install Ubuntu 14.04 on top of 12.04, dont format anything- this way you retain your personal files.
After installation reboot and update, the new installation will probably find your old programs and update them too.
Best of luck!